# Remap key combination (steelseries keyboard)

Tags: autohotkey, key-bindings

Within the steelseries engine it is very easy to change the basic key functionality. But I can not find an option to change what happens when you press a modifier key like 'shift' + that specific key.

I was wondering if anyone knows either a way of doing this in Steelseries engine, or another way perhaps using AHK or something of the sort?

Comment: Posted an answer below on how to capture a key combo with `shift` in it. If Im not following what you are asking feel free to let me know.

Comment: It's in first page of AHK help ....

Comment: Was mostly asking if someone knew how to do it in Steelseries itself, pointing out AHK as I know it is a possible solution. But I see it as a last option kind of thing.

Comment: I give up with steelseries. I have downloaded the AHK and apply the changes as in @ZackTarr answer

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to do with the key binding. But yes you can capture `shift+ another key` with the syntax below.

```
+A::
MsgBox, Shift A was pressed!
return

+B::
Send, Shift B was pressed!
Return
```

To see a full list of the modifier hotkeys and the symbol to use for each you can look at [Hotkeys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)